# Create "Image with formatting and constraints for publishing" site column programmatically

Tags: 2013, content-type

How can I create site column with "Image with formatting and constraints for publishing" content type programmatically in FeatureActivated method?

I need to add this site column to the List

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add a Site Column, following function will help:

```
public void CreateSiteColumn(SPWeb site, string columnXml, Guid columnGuid)
{
    if (site.AvailableFields.Contains(columnGuid) == false)
    {
            site.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(columnXml);
            site.Update();
    }
}
```

Than add the column to content type:

```
public void AddColumnToContentType(SPWeb site, string contentTypeName, Guid columnGuid, string columnTitle, bool isRequired)
{
    var contentType = site.ContentTypes[contentTypeName];
    if (contentType != null)
    {
        var isFieldAdded = contentType.FieldLinks.Cast<SPFieldLink>().Any(fieldRef => fieldRef.Id == columnGuid);

        if (!isFieldAdded)
        {
             var field = site.Fields[columnGuid];
             var fieldLink = new SPFieldLink(field);
             fieldLink.Required = isRequired;
             fieldLink.DisplayName = columnTitle;
             contentType.FieldLinks.Add(fieldLink);
             contentType.Update(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Than adding content type to the List

```
SPList list = site.Lists.TryGetList("List Title");
SPContentType contentType = site.ContentTypes["Content Type Title"];
list.ContentTypes.Add(contentType);
```

Using the above to add Image column

```
var fieldGuid = new Guid("guid-here");
var fieldXml = string.Format("<Field ID=\"{0}\" Type=\"Image\" Name=\"FieldName\" Description=\"\" DisplayName=\"Field Display Name\" StaticName=\"FieldName\" Group=\"Site Column Group\" Hidden=\"FALSE\" Required=\"FALSE\" RichText=\"TRUE\" RichTextMode=\"ThemeHtml\"></Field>", fieldGuid.ToString("B"));

fieldsManager.CreateSiteColumn(site, fieldXml, fieldGuid);
```